# Scrollbar with white background

Tags: css, macos, scrollbar, macos-sonoma

I'm developing an application with React, recently I noticed that it's appeared a scrollbar with white background, till some days ago I was seeing the normal one (track with grey dark and background transparent).

[image: scrollbar with white background]

I don't understand what cause this rendering, I researched a lot but I didn't find any solution. I don't think it's something related to the CSS even if I also tried some CSS solutions like `color-scheme: dark` and others.

I'm using Mac OS X, maybe it's something related to the OS, in another Mac this is not happening.
In Mac the settings, I can see:

[image: 3 options for scrollbar]

If I select the option 2, "when scrolling", I see just the scrollbar just when I'm scrolling, this is not what I want but at least it's the default one without background, but if I drag the track, I see again the background.
If I select the first option, that it's the default one, I see again the white background, but in another Mac with the same OS version "Sonoma", I see the other scrollbar.

This happening in every browser, I hope someone can help me, I never had this issue before and I really don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Have you tried the `webkit-scrollbar` property?

Comment: @Ermi I tried `webkit-scrollbar`, `webkit-scrollbar-thumb` and also `webkit-scrollbar-track`. I think the issue could be related with the second monitor maybe, I tried to restart the Mac disconnecting the second monitor and it seems I see the default scrollbar. I really don't get how the second monitor could have some effects on the scrollbar aspect.

Answer (score 1):

Can you confirm if the `scrollbar-width` has been set to thin?
Regardless of the `webkit-scrollbar` value, you can see that it applies the default style.
For additional colors, you need to use the `scrollbar-color` property. For example, `scrollbar-color: black white;`

You can find more information on the updated features in Chrome on this blog: [https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-chrome-121#css-updates"](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-chrome-121#css-updates%22)